# MySQL: Group by and aggregate_function with condition

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have this table

```
  id | idDevice | type | color 
  -----------------------------
  1  |  1       | a    | red
  2  |  1       | b    | green
  3  |  1       | c    | red
  4  |  2       | a    | blue
  5  |  2       | b    | red
```

Each `idDevice` has at least one `type` with red `color`.

I would like to get for each `idDevice` one `type` that has `color` red (thats not unique) with an GROUP BY statement like this:

```
SELECT idDevice, 
    CASE WHEN color = red THEN type END as redType 
FROM table 
GROUP BY idDevice
```

Unfortunately the above does not work, because it sometimes returns a NULL redType even though there exists a type with red color. Is it possible to get a correct redType with the GROUP BY statement?

I am looking for this:

```
  idDevice | redType
  -----------------------------
    1      | a    
    2      | b
```

or this outcome:

```
  idDevice | redType
  -----------------------------
    1      | c    
    2      | b
```

Comment: I don't understand 'or' in this context

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `CASE` for this, just `WHERE`.

```
SELECT idDevice, MAX(type) AS redType
FROM table
WHERE color = 'red'
GROUP BY idDevice
```

Comment: why use max() function

Comment: You need to use something to select which type in the group to select.